# Seaborn Heatmap Colorbar does not show Zero

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, heatmap

I created custom tick labels for my heatmap colorbar. The zero does not get printed. Is there a way to also print the zero?

My code:

```
import seaborn as sns

Granger2 = Granger
Granger2.columns = Granger_colnames
Granger2.index = Granger_rownames
cbar_ticks = [0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,25)) 
sns.heatmap(Granger2, cmap=rvb, cbar=True, ax=ax,linewidths=.5,cbar_kws={"orientation": "horizontal", "pad":0.01,"ticks": cbar_ticks})
ax.xaxis.tick_top() # x axis on top
ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top')

#Remove ticks
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', length=0)

# Drawing the frame
ax.axhline(y = 0, color='k',linewidth = 1)
ax.axhline(y = Granger2.shape[0], color = 'k',linewidth = 1)  
ax.axvline(x = 0, color = 'k', linewidth = 1)
ax.axvline(x = Granger2.shape[1], color = 'k', linewidth = 1)

cbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar
cbar.ax.axhline(y = 0, color='k',linewidth = 1)
cbar.ax.axhline(y = 1, color = 'k',linewidth = 1)  
cbar.ax.axvline(x = 0, color = 'k', linewidth = 1)
cbar.ax.axvline(x = 1, color = 'k', linewidth = 1)
cbar.ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', length=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `sns.heatmap(..., vmin=0, vmax=1)`

Comment: Just settung vmin=0 worked!

Comment: If `vmin` is not set, it is calculated as the minimum of the data. Apparently, the minimum of your data is slightly larger than 0.